# lambda in lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Can anybody explain me whats wrong i am doing here -

```
multiArray = [
    ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
]
search ='four'
p1 = list(filter(lambda outerEle: search == outerEle, multiArray[0]))
p = list(filter(lambda multiArrayEle: list(filter(lambda innerArrayEle: search == innerArrayEle, multiArrayEle)), multiArray))
print (p1)
print (p)
```

The result i am getting here is

```
['four']
[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']]
```

while i am expecting

```
[['four'],['four'],['four']]
```

Comment: You're trying to do *far* too much stuff in a single line. When you have a lambda in a lambda *and* your code doesn't work, that's a sign that you should split your code into more, shorter, readable lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @fuglede's answer is really the answer to your question, you can archive the result you want by changing your outer `filter` to `map`:

```
p = list(map(lambda multiArrayEle: list(filter(lambda innerArrayEle: search == innerArrayEle, multiArrayEle)), multiArray))
```

Comment: Thanks Bohdan. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In your second `filter`, you are using a `list` as a predicate (as opposed to simply a `bool` as you do in the first `filter`); now, this implicitly applies the built-in method `bool` to each element `list`, and for a list `l`, `bool(l)` is true exactly when `l` is non-empty:

```
In [4]: bool([])
Out[4]: False

In [5]: bool(['a'])
Out[5]: True
```

This allows you to pick out, for example, all the non-empty lists in a list of lists:

```
In [6]: ls = [['a'], [], ['b']]

In [7]: list(filter(lambda l: l, ls))
Out[7]: [['a'], ['b']]
```

Thus, in your case, at the end of the day, your `filter` ends up giving you all lists for which `'four'` appears, which is all of them.

From your given example, it's not immediately obvious what you are trying to achieve as all the inputs are identical, but my guess is that it's something like the following:

```
In [19]: multiArray = [
    ...:     ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'four'],
    ...:     ['one', 'two', 'three', 'for', 'five'],
    ...:     ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    ...: ]

In [20]: [list(filter(lambda x: x == search, l)) for l in multiArray]
Out[20]: [['four', 'four'], [], ['four']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However what if i want to use lambda inside lambda. You might understood what i want to achieve. I want to search all lists inside a list for a particular word and want to get that searched list.